# How can I make re.findall('a.*c', 'abcbc') match abc instead of abcbc

Tags: python, regex

In Python

How can I make `re.findall('a.*c', 'abcbc')` match `abc` instead of `abcbc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 'non-greedy' matchers:

```
>>> re.findall('a.*?c', 'abcbc')
['abc']
```

Answer (score -1):

As

```
>>> re.findall('a.*?c','abbbc')
>>> ['abbbc']
```

I am not sure whether that's you want.

If you just need 'abc' (only one letter in middle, instead of only one type of letter in middle), it's better to use:

```
>>> re.findall('a.?c','abbbc')
>>> []
```

"." means any letter, "*" means any length and "?" means one or zero, ".*" may be calculated before apply "?", so it depends on your need for which case to use.